# Unity how to crate custom console

Tags: unity-game-engine, debugging, console

So I found out that unity's console is very limited and it could use a bit more features and tools(like a way to filter logs based on namespace/class/type/extra , or a way to use commands(in editor , not in the game itself)) , so I wanted to make one for my own , but after 3 days of research I haven't found anything that could help me in the slightest.

So I need some help to find a hint on what should I do or where should I look.

Thank you.

Comment: Aren't there already enough [Assets](https://assetstore.unity.com/hp?free=true&q=Console&orderBy=1) that can do that? ;)

Comment: Not anything useful.

Comment: Well I know that there are some that support exactly what you named (filter logs by namespace, type, custom tags) and I didn't really get what you mean by `commands` but there are multiple Unity built-in ways for trigger methods via button click etc ;) But well, knowing now that there already are Assets you know: Yes, you can create a custom console. All you need is an `EditorWindow` and you fill it via a listener to [Application.logMessageReceived](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceived.html) the rest is just making you way through the API ^^

Comment: And how to use call stack?

Comment: I have the stack trace but I don't know how use it( how to open logs( like the thing that happens when you double-click on a log in console ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems.

1. How to get logs.
2. How to have a Log Call Back method.

---

1_For the first problem we should use `Application.logMessageReceived` receive and store logs.

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static List<LogEntry> Logs = new List<LogEntry>();

    void Start()
    {
        //Remove it ones , just in case
        Application.logMessageReceived -= HandleLog;
        Application.logMessageReceived += HandleLog;
    }

    private static void HandleLog(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        Logs.Add(new LogEntry(logString, stackTrace, type));
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class LogEntry
{

    public string Message;
    public string StackTrace;
    public LogType Type;

    // You can not remove this
    public LogEntry() { }

    public LogEntry(string message, string stackTrace, LogType type)
    {
        Message = message;
        StackTrace = stackTrace;
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

---

2_For the second one `StackTrace` is what we need to use(from `LogEntry.StackTrace`) which is something gives you something like this:

```
test
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
Test:OnStart() (at Assets/Scripts/Test.cs:40)
```

As you can see `(at Assets/Scripts/Test.cs:40)` contains both the location and the line , so it can be used with `AssetDatabase.OpenAsset`.here is a method to make your life a little easier.

```
public static void LogCallback(string stackTrace)
{
    int startingPoint = stackTrace.IndexOf("Assets/", StringComparison.Ordinal);
    int middlePoint = stackTrace.IndexOf(":", startingPoint, 
    StringComparison.Ordinal);
    int finalPoint = stackTrace.IndexOf(")", middlePoint, StringComparison.Ordinal);

    string adders = stackTrace.Substring(startingPoint, middlePoint - startingPoint);
    
    int lineNumber = Int32.Parse(stackTrace.Substring(middlePoint + 1, finalPoint - middlePoint - 1));

    AssetDatabase.OpenAsset(AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<MonoScript>(adders), lineNumber); 
}
```

Now you can make any function that you want on top of this.